# What to do after accidental deletion of Python3

Tags: 16.04, command-line, package-management, dependencies, gnome-terminal

As you may guess, Ubuntu desktop Interface namely menu bar is not shown and Terminal is not reachable.

However, there is still hope. Via `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, I can type commands.

Problem is, Python3.6.3 and related programs i.e. Unity are severely broken and when I try to (re)install the unmet dependencies, it is almost an endless chain.

I followed the chain until it reaches to a point where no other dependencies exist, yet installation is not successful for some reason.

I suspect that I need to manually direct files to a correct directories.

Before I do something, I thought a proper guidance would be helpful.

P.S. I am aware that in the worse case scenario, I need to install fresh Ubuntu.

P.S.2. I have gone through many sources, yet I could not find any proper walk through.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed Python files by hand (like with `rm -rf`), you can try to fix your installation with this set of commands. (It finds all installed python-related packages and then reinstalls them):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i python | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Due to around 20 `hash sum mismatch` errors it is not fully done. What else am I missing?

Comment: Ok, after a reboot I make it run. But, missing packages are libpython3.5 kind of packages and I receive errors with `Reinstallation of packageName is not possible, it cannot be downloaded`. One liner is not working properly for **python3**

Comment: After using purge before installing broken packages, python3 packages are installed. Problems with Unity packages should be solved. Then, ubuntu-desktop can be installed.

Comment: You broke your system, not me. I just proposed a solution.